# What's the best way to pull random numbers from source array of numbers untill there is no unique values left in the source array?

Tags: javascript, random, closures

I need to create a makeRandom function that accepts a range of numbers as an array, where the first number is the beginning of the range, the second is the end including this number in the range. The result of this function should be a function, and the call returns a random number from the range. The numbers returned must be unique. If I run out of unique numbers, have to return null.

It should work like this :

```
const getRandom = makeRandom([1, 5]);
getRandom() === 3
getRandom() === 4
getRandom() === 5
getRandom() === 2
getRandom() === 1
getRandom() === null
getRandom() === null
```

So I tried :

```js
function makeRandom(numbers) {
  return () => {
    let randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      randNumber += numbers[i];

      if (randNumber === numbers[i]) {
        return true;
      }

      if (randNumber === numers[i].length) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    if (!numbers) {
      return null;
    }
  };
}
```

But it's not working. So what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add all values in an array and splice the array if the array has a length or return `null`.

```js
const
    makeRandom = ([min, max]) => {
        const values = [];
        while (min <= max) values.push(min++);
        return () => values.length
            ? values.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length), 1)[0]
            : null;
    },
    getRandom = makeRandom([1, 5]);

console.log(getRandom());
console.log(getRandom());
console.log(getRandom());
console.log(getRandom());
console.log(getRandom());
console.log(getRandom());
console.log(getRandom());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would personally generate the list of numbers. I would shuffle them which is a bit better than random distribution. I would then pop them off the array.

```js
// Fisher-Yates shuffle
function shuffle(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return array;
}

// create a range of numbers
function range(size, startAt = 0) {
  return [...Array(size).keys()].map(i => i + startAt);
}

function makeRandom(low, high) {
  const numbers = shuffle(range(high - low + 1, low));
  return function () {
    return numbers.length ? numbers.pop() : null;
  }
}


var myRandom = makeRandom(5,10);
console.log(myRandom());
console.log(myRandom());
console.log(myRandom());
console.log(myRandom());
console.log(myRandom());
console.log(myRandom());
console.log(myRandom());
console.log(myRandom());
```